# How can I add Ajax link into Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, routes

In my helper code I add Ajax link as follows.

```
<%= link_to 'name', events_path(@event), :remote => true %>
```

When I run my application it will show "We're sorry, but something went wrong." I couldn't understand why is this happened. Can anybody help me to correct this?

Comment: there are no errors in both browser and server log.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is it supposed to do? I suppose you must add some javascript to be executed once the request is finished. But there seems to be a problem with the name of the link, should it not be named event_path(@event) (not plural events), or just @event should do I guess.